# Given two subspaces $N,W$ of $V$ find a linear transformation $T:V\to V$ such that its kernel is $N$ and is range is $W$.

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

If $N$ and $W$ are subspaces of $V$ such that $\dim(V/N) = \dim W$, then there exists at least one element $A$ of $L(V,V)$ such that $\mbox{ker}(T) = N$ and $\mbox{range}(T) = W$.

Two related problem

i) Given $N$ subspace of $V$, find a linear transformation $T:V\to V$ with kernel $N$.

ii) Given $W$ subspace of $V$, find a linear transformation $S:V\to V$ with range $W$.

I could solve, for i) extend a basis $\{ v_i \}$ of $N$ to one $\{ v_i \} \cup \{ v_j \}$ for $V$ and set $T(v_i) = 0$ and $T(v_j) = v_j$. For ii) extend a basis $\{ v_i \}$ for $W$ to a basis $\{ v_i \} \cup \{ v_k \}$ for $V$ and set $S(v_i) = v_i$ and $S(v_k) = 0$. But I a have problems with the more general situation. I have a idea how it might work, by extending a basis for $N\cap W$ to a basis for $N$ and $W$ separately, and then the union of all these basis vectors must span a space of dimension $\dim(V) - \dim(N\cap W)$ and then extending this basis to one of $V$ and on the added vector use some isomorphism between there spanned space and $N\cap W$ to construct a linear transformation, but I have problem how to make these idea's precise, any help? (btw. I am also considering infinite dimensional vector spaces, which makes a clean formulation also more difficult for me)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Choose a basis of $\;N\;:\;\;\{v_1,...,v_k\}\;$ , complete it to a basis of the whole space: $\;\{v_1,...,v_k,v_{k+1},...,v_n\}\;$.

By the given info, there exists a basis $\;\{w_1,...,w_{n-k}\}\;$ of $\;W\;$ , so define on the above basis of $\;V\;$ :

$$T:V\to V\;,\;\;\;T(v_i)=\begin{cases}0&,\;\;1\le i\le k\\{}\\w_{i-k}&,\;\;k+1\le i\le n\end{cases}$$

and extend by linearity. No need to mess around with the intersection and stuff.