# Given linear maps $T:V\to W$ and $S:V\to W$ does there exist linear map $F:V\to W$ with $\ker F=\ker T\cap \ker S$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Given linear maps $T:V\to W$ and $S:V\to W$ does there exist a linear map $F:V\to W$ with  $\ker F=\ker T\cap  \ker S$, where $V$ and $W$ are different vector spaces?

What if $V=W$?
The answer is in [Given two subspaces $N,W$ of $V$ find a linear transformation $T:V\to V$ such that its kernel is $N$ and is range is $W$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/561458/given-two-subspaces-n-w-of-v-find-a-linear-transformation-tv-to-v-such-th?rq=1)

If not, are there any conditions on $T,S,V,W$ that will make it so? Let's start with examples of those four that prevent that.

Feel free to change the tag (subject), to expose this question to people who are interested in delving deep in this question.

Thanks

Comment: Generally, no. For some particular $S$ and $T$, or if $W = \{0\}$, such an $F$ exists.

Comment: I am using old computers that don't allow installing programs.

Comment: so much hostility. I did not know what you meant. I will change it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a trivial operator:

$\ker F$ is a subspace so it will have a basis $u_{1},...,u_{k}$. Then extend it to basis $u_{1},...,u_{k},w_{1},...,w_{n-k}$ for $V$ ($\dim(V)=n$). Also, let $f$ be a basis element of $W$.

Then define: $F(v):=\left\{\begin{matrix}0 & {\rm if}~  v\in \ker F\\ f & v\notin \ker F
\end{matrix}\right.$

$F$ in terms of $T$.

$F(v):=0$  if  $v\in \ker F$ and $F(w_{i})=t_{i}$ (where $t_{1},...,t_{l}$ is the basis of ${\rm Im}(T)$) but change it where it doesn't make sense according to the l,n-k and $\dim(W)$.